# Classify and populate object from untyped or difficult to typed Rest Response

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'd like to make some client program using RestSharp and Json.Net. I want to deserialize and classify some JSON response from Rest service Api.

I ask to the service like this

```
http://api.someservice.com/Term?parentId=123
```

And the response of the service is like blow.

```
{
    "statusCode":"OK",
    "123":
    [
       {"name":"Foo","childId":"4567","parentId":"123"},
       {"name":"Bar","childId":"8901","parentId":"123"},
    ]
]
```

It seems to be classified like blow.

```
public class 123
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string childId { get; set; }
    public string parentId { get; set; }
 }

public class RootObject
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public List<123> 123 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is the name of class and property are changed by request("123") each time.
Anyway, My purpose is to make a instance of each {"name....} strings.

I'd like to know the best way to populate each raw of name and childId using RestSharp and Json.Net.
Or, is there any way to ignore "123":[] and just get my interesting part of the code?

Thank you for your time.